# Finding Max Value of Row but error: object of type '_csv.reader' has no len()

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to use 2 functions in conjunction. Basically I'm trying to import a csv file that is a series of rows with values I need. Then I'm trying to find the maximum value of each row using the second function "findPeaks". I'm getting the error that the rows I'm trying to look at have no length, but they should be arrays of values. What is my error? Thank you for your help.

```
def PSD(pulseData, pulseDataTraining):

     import csv;
     import numpy as np;
     import math
     photonTraining = 0; 

     with open(pulseDataTraining,'r') as csvfile:
         photonTraining = csv.reader(csvfile);
         print(photonTraining)
         for row in photonTraining:
             findPeaks(photonTraining,-30)  

     if photonTraining == 0:
         print("this is a string")

     return np.max(photonTraining)
```

and the second function:

```
def findPeaks(pulse, thresh):

     import numpy as np;
     import scipy as sp;

     peakVal = 0;
     for i in range(0,len(pulse)-1):
         while(pulse[i]<thresh):
             if np.abs(pulse[i]) < np.abs(pulse[i+1]):
                 peakVal = pulse[i+1];
             else:
                 peakVal = pulse[i];


     return peakVal;
```

Comment: Fix your indentation or it is impossible to say what is going on.

Comment: But, actually, in your for-loop you are passing `photonReader`, which is a *`csv.reader`* object, to `findPeaks`. You meant to pass `row`. Which by the way, will be a *`list`* of values, not an array.

Comment: Also remove those semicolons.  Python isn't C or Java.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I believe I know where to go from here. I just need to find out how to go through a list in a for loop as I have never done that before.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have, you have just been conflating lists and arrays, a very common mistake. It works like iterating over any other container in python. In other words, `for i in range(0,len(pulse)-1):` will work.

Comment: I get the error:

TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

so I think I need to find a way to make my thresh value a string or convert the string value in the list to an int?

Answer (score 0):

Change to the following:

```
def PSD(pulseData, pulseDataTraining):
    with open(pulseDataTraining, 'r') as csvfile:
        # Create a csv.reader from Filehandle
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        # Create a List of Peak Values per Row from CSV
        photonTraining_peak = \
            [findPeaks(photonTraining, -30) for photonTraining in csv.reader(csvfile)]

    print('row_max:{}'.format(photonTraining_peak),)
    return np.max(photonTraining_peak)
```

Your `findPeaks(...` will raise

```
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Change to

```
import csv
import numpy as np

def findPeaks(pulse, thresh):
    # pulse is Type List of String
    sorted_pulse = sorted(pulse, reverse=True)
    print(sorted_pulse)

    peakVal = 0
    for s in sorted_pulse:
        v = int(s)
        if v < thresh:
            if np.abs(peakVal) < np.abs(v):
                peakVal = v
        else:
            break
    return peakVal
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***